# Iterar sobre sublistas dentro de una lista

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Actualmente tengo una lista de la clase Actividad, esta clase, entre otras propiedades, tiene una que es IdOperario.

El caso es que yo cargo de base de datos todas las actividades de todos los operarios en la lista lAux y lo que necesito es a partir de esa gran lista poder tratar todas las actividades de cada operario, para ello intento hacer los siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver da error de compilación.

Necesitaria poder tratar todas las sublistas generadas con cada IdOperador distinto dentro del foreach, o algun tratamiento similar.
Gracias por la ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Edit: Pongo el código con la modificacion de Einer, funciona bien, lo unico si se puede optimizar.

Comment: podrias agregar el codigo, y el mensaje de error y quitar la imagen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IdOperario` es de tipo `int` y cuando haces `Select(x=>x.IdOperario)` estas creando una lista de `int`, no de `Actividad` por lo que te dice que no puedes convertir un tipo `int` a `List<Actividad>`.

Asi que cambia:

```
foreach(List<Actividad> lista in lUx.Select(x=>X.IdOperario).Distinct().ToList())
{

}
```

Por:

```
foreach(int idOperatorio in lUx.Select(x=>X.IdOperario).Distinct().ToList())
{

}
```

**Actualizacion:**

Como mencionas que necesitas agrupar por actividad y esa misma clase que tiene los datos que necesitas, puedes utilizar `GroupBy(x=>X.IdOperario)` donde te dara la lista agrupada por el `IdOperario`:

```
foreach( IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, List<Actividad>> actividadesAgrupadas in lUx.GroupBy(x=>X.IdOperario))
{
    foreach(Actividad actividad in actividadesAgrupadas)
    {
        // actividad agrupada por el operario
        Console.WriteLine(actividad.InicioTrabajo);
    }
}
```

Comment: ah, y luego seria filtrar lAux por los elementos que compartan el mismo id, lo pruebo, gracias

Comment: @Veelicus creo que esto no es exactamente lo que buscas. Probablemente lo que realmente buscas es un `GroupBy`, ya que esta solución te obligará a hacer una segunda consulta, pero sin saber la estructura de tu clase `Actividad` es dificil decirte mas.

Comment: @Pikoh La clase actividad tiene varios campos, los dos mas importantes para este tema es el IdOperario, que indica que operario es, InicioTrabajo que es cuando comenzo a trabajar y Duracion, que es el tiempo que ha estado trabajando. El tema consiste en para cada operario saber todas las actividades que ha realizado en un periodo de fechas, y por cada actividad encontrada generar una linea en un excel y luego la suma de todas las duraciones de esas actividades. Me temo que si que necesito dar dos vueltas, pensaba que se podria hacer un freach como pongo en la pregunta pero parece ser que no :(

Comment: @Veelicus y la clase actividad tiene la informacion de `InicioTrabajo` y `Duracion`?

Comment: @Einer si, gracias por el interes

Answer (score 4):

Aunque la respuesta de @Einer es totalmente correcta, probablemente lo que buscas es un `GroupBy` mas que un `Select`. Si lo que quieres es ver todas las actividades de cada Operario, lo mas lógico es agruparlas por el IdOperario para posteriormente recorrer en un bucle cada actividad de dicho operario. Yo haría algo asi:

```
foreach (var agrupado in lUx.GroupBy(x => x.IdOperario))
{
    //en agrupado.Key tienes el IdOperario
    foreach(var actividad in agrupado)
    {
        //en actividad vas recorriendo cada actividad del operario
        //podrias acceder a actividad.InicioTrabajo, actividad.Duracion, actividad.IdOperario...
        //
    }
}
```

O, si lo que necesitas es una lista de cada operario para procesarla, simplemente:

```
foreach (var agrupado in lUx.GroupBy(x => x.IdOperario))
{
    List<Actividad> lista = agrupado.ToList();
    int? secs = lista.Sum(x=>x.Duracion);
    GestionExcel.generaInformeIndividual(lista, secs);  
}
```

Comment: esta solucion que me das es muy interesante, pero a mi me interesaria tener una lista con todas las actividades de cada operario, para asi podersela pasar directamente al generador de informes en excel

Comment: @Veelicus mira la segunda parte de mi respuesta. De todas maneras, es importante que pegues el código en lugar de hacer capturas, facilitarás mucho el trabajo al que quiere responderte

Comment: si, esta solucion es mas optima que la anterior, muchas gracias, le pondre como respuesta correcta a la de Einer porque fue el primero que me respondio con una respuesta correcta y me parece que es lo justo. Gracias.

Comment: @Veelicus: Lo justo es que des un voto positivo a todas las respuestas que te parecen útiles, pero aceptar la que consideras la mejor respuesta sin importar quién contestó primero. No se trata de un concurso de velocidad. Toma en cuenta que cuando aceptas una respuesta, esta automáticamente aparece como la primera y la más visible, de modo que es la que otras personas van a ver primero al encontrar esta pregunta en un futuro y la que otras personas probablemente van a usar como referencia.

Comment: @sstan Buenas, he puesto positivos a ambas respuestas porque igualmente validas para mi, si embargo a la hora de decidir cual es la unica que se puede poner como correcta, me parece mas correcto darselo a Einer, mas que nada porque su primera respuesta ya solventaba mi problema, el resto son mejoras de rendimiento que agradezco mucho. Un saludo.

Comment: @Veelicus: Por supuesto la decisión es tuya. Solo quería aclarar que no hay obligación de dársela al primero que contesta, y que también es bueno tomar en cuenta los beneficios para futuros lectores.

Comment: @sstan  estoy de acuerdo